# Is it possible to pass non-user information through an html form?

Tags: php, html, forms

Apologies in advance for the noob question:

I want an html form that passes both 1) user-defined variables, and 2) pre-defined variables to a php script.

Here's the html:

```
<form action="update_db.php" method="post">
Before Rating: <input type="number" name="rating"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="update_db.php" method="post">
After Rating: <input type="number" name="rating"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here's update_db.php:

```
$rating=$_POST["rating"]; 
mysql_connect("localhost", "uname", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ratings_table
(rating, before_or_after) VALUES($rating,$before_or_after)")
or die(mysql_error());
```

As you can see, I want to call the same php script for both a 'before' rating form and an 'after' rating form, then update a database with both the user-defined variable ('rating'), and a pre-defined variable ('before_or_after'). I would like 'before_or_after' to be '1' when update_db.php is called by the 'before' form, and '2' when called by the 'after' form.

I am certain that there is an easy answer to this, or that I am thinking about this in the completely wrong way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I may need more clarification on this...It kind of just sounds like you want to have two different pages that share mostly the same HTML (through require() or include()), or one page that checks a $_GET conditional to determine which view the user is looking at and make slight adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

So why not just use a different post variable in your HTML and write a little extra PHP?

```
<form action="update_db.php" method="post">
Before Rating: <input type="number" name="rating_before"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="update_db.php" method="post">
After Rating: <input type="number" name="rating_after"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now we just check which one is set in the PHP.

```
if(isset($_POST["rating_after"])) $rating = $_POST["rating_after"]; 
if(isset($_POST["rating_before"])) $rating = $_POST['rating_before'];
mysql_connect("localhost", "uname", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ratings_table
(rating, before_or_after) VALUES($rating,$before_or_after)")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

change the form to this:

```
<form action="update_db.php" method="post">
Before Rating: <input type="number" name="before_rating">
<input type="hidden" name="before_or_after" value="before"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<form action="update_db.php" method="post">
After Rating: <input type="number" name="after_rating">
<input type="hidden" name="before_or_after" value="after"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and your php use $_POST['before_or_after']

now for the WARNINGS mysql_* should no longer be used and this is open to an SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="update_db.php?mood=1" method="post">
Before Rating: <input type="number" name="rating"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="update_db.php?mood=2" method="post">
After Rating: <input type="number" name="rating"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and on update_db.php initialize $before_or_after with
`$before_or_after = $_GET['mood'];`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use $_GET to solve the problem:

```
<form action="update_db.php?r=1" method="post">
Before Rating: <input type="number" name="rating"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>   
<form action="update_db.php?r=2" method="post">
After Rating: <input type="number" name="rating"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

then in PHP:

```
$r = (int)$_GET['r'];
if($r==1){//it's before 

}
else{//it's after

}
```

However, please, beware, that $_GET and 'hidden' values cannot be 100% trusted, while some users can intentionally replace them, for example, with JavaScript (e.g. they can post an "after rating" form with the parameter pointing out it is "before rating"). If it does not make a lot of sense for users to post one form instead of another, then do this way.